# Adding additional object properties in PaperJS to export them

Tags: json, paperjs

I try to export to JSON and import them after, in a paperJS project. The problem is the following.
The object has a additional properties like 'idLine' for example, but, when I export the item, it loose all additional properties.
By the way, the properties are added with:

```
    new paper.Path(strPath, {idLine : 1})
```

I find something similar in fabricJS, but nothing more than this.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Adding-additional-object-properties-to-serialized-JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To export data along with paper Items, you just need to set your data in the [Item.data](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#data) attribute.

For example:

```
 var cirle = new Path.Circle({ center: new Point(150, 50),  radius: 25 });
 cirle.fillColor = 'darkGreen'
 cirle.data = 'someData'

 var rectangle = new Path.Rectangle(new Point(50, 100), new Point(250, 150));
 rectangle.fillColor = 'darkBlue'
 rectangle.data = {size: 50, message: 'some other data'}

 var json = project.exportJSON();
```

[Here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/ZdBNT4QwEAbgv9L0AiSEsJtwYePFNTHxoMY9iodaRuhSOmTaVSPhv9uC6JrtqZ2PN086ciN64CU/dOBky1MusQ7vd0FMKtLArpiBD/YoXJvtFUkN8VgZ5o8E44DKpY3KuHhT5Ckr8iRdBkjU6mRLti0qMyW7ylRmjszelNZ71Eg+PKoFdbcEYKK1XQsnQsdiDzf+HoXNACKQTpjmP+ppLcZ/kODY5B5yhtvORa9bJL9Zl5prfYLofOIHNFr1BSULOT1YKxr/mJEMXQvEwlg0rdijReOXBsKjD8rgc0Byd4eH+zgAJBqLPlpjE4fJZOf//pVAdEPQWl4+v0zf) is a sketch that exports to JSON with the data of the paths.